# How can I compare (like isBefore) date with diferentes zones

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, momentjs

How can I compare two dates using moment-timezone, I'm trying:

```
const mtz = require ('moment-timezone');

let dt = new Date ();
let tokyo = mtz(dt).tz("Asia/Tokyo"); // JST +12
let new_york = mtz(dt).tz("America/New_York"); // MDT -4

console.log (new_york.isBefore (tokyo)); // returns false
console.log (tokyo.isBefore (new_york)); // returns false too
```

Why both of then returns false?
Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is translating the same time (dt) into two different time zones.  The translations  tokyo and new_york are two different ways of stating the exact same time.

if you start out with:

```
let new_yort_dt = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
let tokyo_dt = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo"})
```

then go through the process of creating your moment timezone objects, what do you get?